# grunt build gives Error code: EISDIR when trying to package fonts in AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

When I `grunt build` my AngularJS app `grunt-rev` has a problem dealing with the fonts. It will create the font folders just fine but does not place any fonts in them. Here is what it shows me.

`Running "rev:dist" (rev) task
dist/scripts/scripts.js >> a3e641ec.scripts.js
dist/styles/main.css >> 970b8797.main.css
Warning: Unable to read "dist/fonts/Aller" file (Error code: EISDIR). Use --force to continue.`

`grunt-rev` in my `Gruntfile.js`

```
rev: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 14):

I finally solved this problem by using the double asterisk `**` method to match all the sub directories recursively. I don't know why that method was not used in my original **Gruntfile.js**. Instead it used the `{,*/}*` which did not behave recursively for some reason. So here is my new `rev` object in my **Gruntfile.js**

```
rev: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/**/*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/**/*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/fonts/**/*.ttf'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: The thing that fixed it was that you specified a file extension `.ttf`, not that you switched from `*` to `**/*`.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. [They have a bug about it in version 0.1.0](https://github.com/cbas/grunt-rev/issues/29).

A workaround is to specify a file extension.

Before:

```
rev: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= config.dist %>/',
      src: [
        'images/**/*'
      ]
    }]
  }
}
```

After:

```
rev: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= config.dist %>/',
      src: [
        'images/**/*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png}'
      ]
    }]
  }
}
```